How can I set a filter with date for a datetime field?
Could you guide me on configuring a filter within the EasyAdminBundle interface to exclusively filter by date for a datetime field in the CRUD List interface? My expectation is to have an intuitive Only Date Filter Interface available for this purpose

You could just configure a filter for your datetime field and filter by date only in the UI:
class UserCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return User::class;
    }

    public function configureFilters(Filters $filters): Filters
    {
        return $filters->add('createdAt');
    }
}


Or you can create a custom filter following these steps as shown in the documentation: https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/filters.html#custom-filters

I need only Date Filter not Datetime
